# Print out every n-th item of array list depending on the number of items

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> melody = new ArrayList<>();
```

`melody` contains strings like "EEAABB", "AAGDFE" ... The size of `melody` may vary.

Now depending on the size of `melody`, I would like to print out every N-th string, and the last few strings.

For example:

1. melody has 2037 elements: print every 100th element and the last 5 elements
2. melody has 100 elements: print every 10th element and the last 5 elements

The 100 and the 10 don't need to be fixed numbers, they are here just for example.

My issue here is how to find out, depending on the size of the list, which n-th element should I print.

I want it to be scalable as much as possible.

I know how to print out elements of the list, but I don't know how to determine with what frequency I would print them on the screen (especially when I have little elements in the array).

Comment: How would we know? Did your assignment not indicate how to calculate `n`?

Comment: "My issue here is how to find out, depending on the size of the list, which n-th element should i print." You have to **define** this rule. Or if this is a homework assignment, you need to ask your teacher. There isn't a fixed way to do this in general.

Comment: no, it didnt, i need to choose myself

Comment: You can make this a method, something like `count(ArrayList<String> list, int n)`. Deciding what `n` actually is would be up to whoever is calling the method.

Comment: One possible rule is if the length of the list is less than 100 print out every 10th element. If the length is between 100 and 1000, then print out every 1000th element. If the length is between 1000 and a million, then print out every 10000th element. etc. But this is only one example of an infinite possible rules. You have to choose one. We can't tell you which one is bets for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I've created that prints every x-th element, `n`, and the last y elements, `last`.

The whole idea is that making this a method will allow the process to work for any arguments that are given to it.

The example I'm using is a list filled with numbers so the process can be seen easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> melody = new ArrayList<>();
    melody.add("1");
    melody.add("2");
    melody.add("3");
    melody.add("4");
    melody.add("5");
    melody.add("6");
    melody.add("7");
    melody.add("8");
    melody.add("9");
    melody.add("10");
    print(melody, 3, 5);
}

private static void print(ArrayList<String> list, int n, int last) {
    ArrayList<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = list.size();

    System.out.println("Every " + n + " elements in the list: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += n) {
        String str = list.get(i);
        filtered.add(str);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    System.out.println("The last " + last + " elements excluding every " + n + " elements in the list:");

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String str = list.get(i);
        if (!filtered.contains(str)) {
            System.out.println(str);
            if (++count == last) break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have assumed that you wish to include the first element in the list when printing every `n`th element. That is, `1 4 7 10` is the output of my example, not `3, 6, 9`.

Output:

```
Every 3 elements in the list: 
1
4
7
10
The last 5 elements excluding every 3 elements in the list:
9
8
6
5
3
```

Comment: ty for the initial idea, i made it simmilar to yours. but i implemented that the last items can not be ones that are print out with every n.
Would (melody.size()%n) ensure that?

Comment: `melody.size() / n` would be how many times `n` fits into `melody`, and `melody.size() % n` would be the remainder of that. Unless I'm missing something here, I'm not sure how that would help solve the second part of the problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's certainly not the only way to go about solving this, but it is probably easier to understand. I add every `n`th element to a different list `filtered`, and then loop through `melody` backwards, printing the elements that are not in `filtered`.